# Serializing JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, serialization, jtabbedpane

In a Java GUI code I use a `JTabbedPane`called `tabpane`. This `tabpane` has dynamic functionality, that is tabs can be added, closed and tab contents may changed by the user.

As far as I know the entire `tabpane` remains in the Random Access Memory during execution. But I need only the currently selected tab to remain in RAM and others not. Others should be written in disk memory and loaded in RAM whenever they are called.

I think it is possible as `JTabbedPane` is a `Serializable` component. But what are the exact procedures to accomplish this?

Comment: Why would one serialize a GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot serialize a partial GUI, but only the whole component graph. One possibility would be to serialize each pane in separate files, and deserialize those when needed, but then you have to manually construct the parent tab and everything above it, which is propably not what you want.

Comment: Actually I plan to design a browser for low memory conditions. How does tabbed browsers like Firefox manage tabs. Do they keep all of them in RAM or any other mechanism? Please share.

Comment: If you do not have ram, use swap.

Comment: f.nasim: Just don't do it. If you ask questions like these, better start with a smaller project. Browsers are some of the most complicated pieces of software around, and to make them useful is a pain in the ***.

Comment: @Daniel I am just experimenting and my browser is not going to be a commercial one. Thanks.

Comment: Do not serialize the tabs... if at all, serialize the data that is rendered within the tabs.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that `JTabbedPane` is `Serializable`. But to the solution of your problem, it will be better to have a properties file, and your program after reading the property file, determine which tabs are required and create a new `JTabbedPane` and use it instead. Serializing the `JTabbedPane` will not prove to be too useful.

Comment: Could you explain the 'property file' more? Is this idea useful for a browser application?

Comment: A property file is a file where you have key value pairs of the form : CreatePanel=1\nEditpanel=0\nDeletePanel=1. [Note that the "\n" actually corresponds to a new line in the property file]. It becomes useful if you want your UI to be configurable at runtime. The process is as follows : Use a specified variable to denote whether that particular panel is to be included or not. If yes, include it in your JTabbedPane else don't. Also the java.util.Property class isvary handy to read, update property files.